# Kernel will not upgrade after installing linux-image on Debian

Tags: linux, kernel, debian-wheezy

I am attempting to upgrade my Linux kernel to 3.2 on my Debian server. I have installed the image package, but even after rebooting I still seem to have my old 2.6 kernel. I am assuming I probably have to do something else to get it to work, could someone help with this?

```
root@myserver:~# uname -r
2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3
root@myserver:~# cat /etc/debian_version
wheezy/sid
root@myserver:~# apt-cache search linux-image
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files
linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64
linux-headers-3.2.0-3-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-3-rt-amd64
linux-image-3.2.0-3-amd64 - Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-3.2.0-3-amd64-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64
linux-image-3.2.0-3-rt-amd64 - Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-3.2.0-3-rt-amd64-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 3.2.0-3-rt-amd64
linux-image-2.6-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (dummy package)
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
nvidia-kernel-3.2.0-3-amd64 - NVIDIA binary kernel module for Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64
nvidia-kernel-3.2.0-3-rt-amd64 - NVIDIA binary kernel module for Linux 3.2.0-3-rt-amd64
linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 - Linux 2.6.32 for 64-bit PCs
root@myserver:~# apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-3-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-3.2.0-3-amd64 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@myserver:~#
```

Answer (score 4):

```
2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3
```

The `el5` is a bit of a giveaway that this isn't a "normal" Debian system, since `el5` implies that it's some kind of RHEL derivative.  Seems that that kernel is an OpenVZ container kernel, which is probably what your provider is using - in which case, you don't control what kernel you run.